# How to end a go program from a goroutine

Tags: go, command-line-interface, channel, goroutine

I'm trying to implement some non-typical behavior in a command line interface written in go.

I have a function that runs for a long time, and I want to have a cleanup function that runs when someone ctrl-c's out of that function.

Here's a mock-up of the code:

```
func longRunningFunction() {
    //some set up stuff
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)

    go func() {
        <-sigs
        fmt.Println("Got an interrupt")
        cleanup()
    }()
    //the long-running command
    fmt.Println("the end")
}
```

In the normal case, using ctrl-c will not be necessary and the function will finish normally. (Because of this, I can't have something (like a channel) in the main thread that blocks until the cleanup goroutine has finished.) However, in the case that a user does press ctrl-c, I would like to end the program immediately, not printing "the end" (and ideally not finishing the long-running command).

That's not happening right now. Currently, the command line output looks like this:

```
...
//long-running-command's output
^CGot an interrupt
//cleanup code's output
$
//more of long-running-command's output
the end
```

I'm confused on a few fronts - why is the program still printing after the prompt returns, and why is "the end" still being printed? How can I avoid this behavior? Is this scenario even possible in go? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're continuing execution after your signal handler. If you want to exit the process, call [`os.Exit`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit):

```
go func() {
    <-sigs
    fmt.Println("Got an interrupt")
    cleanup()
    os.Exit(2)
}()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But doesn't that just end the goroutine? I've tried that before and I get the same command line output.

Comment: @LizFurlan: from the docs: `The program terminates immediately;`. Nothing else will run after that point.

Comment: oh, I see the issue now. `os.Exit(2)` does work (thank you!) but it isn't happening until after everything else gets executed (i.e. "the end" is printed) - do you know if there is a way I can force `cleanup()` and `os.Exit(2)` to happen together?

Comment: @LizFurlan: what would "together" mean in this case? Either you've exited, or you haven't. You could call `os.Exit` from `cleanup`, but if it's the last thing called it's not going to make any difference. `longRunningFunction` simply reaches "the end" before `os.Exit` is called, if you don't want that to happen, you need to stop that yourself somehow.

Comment: sorry, I was unclear. "Together" meaning that `os.Exit(2)` is the first thing that happens after `cleanup()` (as opposed to `fmt.Println("the end")` being executed in between them)

Comment: @LizFurlan: that's what I mean by you having to stop that yourself. You can't count on any execution order of goroutines without synchronization points. Unless you setup some synchronization, e.g. an `isExiting` mutex, there could always be other things happening between `os.Exit` and whatever directly preceded it.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thanks!